# csv import failure when creating a table in pgAdmin4/SQL

Tags: csv, importerror, csv-import

Column headers are importing, but I don't know where they are coming from as they are not included in the csv file as headers. I have tried unchecking them in the initial "columns to import" box, unsuccessfully. My imports keep failing.

[columns being added at import level for csv[failure of csv import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9wE2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Mfu.png)
[columns being autogenerated and not part of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eoOi.png)

Comment: If you don't have columns in the csv as a header row, you should be looking for something to check/uncheck such as "my csv file has headers" or "header row" ... i.e., I mean some option in your import configuration where you turn an option like this on or off.

Comment: The columns being shown are those that the data will be imported into, not the headers in the file. What is strange is that system(xmin,ctid,xmax,etc) are being shown.  So: 1) In the failure message there should be a `Details` link/button. **Copy and paste as text NOT as an image that information to your question**. 2) Also as text provide the  table definition as update to question. 3) Copy and paste a sample of the CSV data.